# add multiple update queries in spring batch JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-batch

I need to run update on two table based on the data i received in my file. The source is one single file.

I tried searching for JdbcBatchItemWriter with multiple queries.

Currently i tried below approach with 1 job and 2 steps - where am using same reader, same processor and same listener in both of the steps - but i think it is repetitive.

```
<batch:job id="batchJob">

    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
        <batch:tasklet>

            <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" processor="myItemProcessor"
                writer="mysqlItemWriter1" commit-interval="1" skip-limit="10">
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="stepListener">
                    </batch:listener>
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" processor="myItemProcessor"
                writer="mysqlItemWriter2" commit-interval="1" skip-limit="10">
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="stepListener">
                    </batch:listener>
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

</batch:job>
```

My itemWriter1 and 2 run update and i need to get the update count for both queries.

This is just i work around i found out , but i think this is not optimal enough

Please let me know if we can use multiple update queries in one single writer. Also suggest if any optimal way.

Thank you

Comment: Use a `CompositeItemWriter` composed by 2 differents `JdbcBatchItemWriter `, one for every query you need to execute

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci , thank you for response , i tried the approach but how do we get the update count for each writer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may approach the problem decorating `JdbcBatchItemWriter`: this decorator is responsible to store in `ExecutionContext` how many items the real writer really write so you can get back later in your step.

```
class CountingItemWriter implements ItemStreamWriter {
  private JdbcBatchItemWriter delegate;
  private int count = 0;
  private final String id;

  CountingItemWriter(String id) {
    this.id = "CountingItemWriter#"+id;
  }

  write(List<?> items) {
    delegate.write(items);
    count += items.size();
  }

  open(ExecutionContext ec) {
    count = getInt(this.id, 0);
  }

  update(ExecutionContext ec) {
    ec.putInt(this.id, count);
  }

  close() {
    // no-op
  }
}
```

Remember to give a different `id` if you have more than one writer to be able to retrieve the right counter for every writer.

Comment: thank you for your reply , the count i need is the number of rows updated by my sql query in each writer or each table as I mentioned earlier , i think the count which you gave me will give the items count , i tried using the writeCount from step execution context , but it gives me count for entire step , not for every item - update

Comment: If `delegate.write()` complete successfully you are sure you wrote `items.size()`; if write throws an exception SB rollback all and restart last chunk using `commit-interval=1`.

Comment: sorry for late remark , yes this was helpful for me